# Why is the first argument of reduce() returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a function that takes in an array as an input. If the integer is positive, it counts it. If the integer is negative, it sums it.

I figured that that the `reduce()` helper in js would be the best way to go about this, but I keep returning undefined for my first argument when it runs.

Here's my code:

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
    let countPositive = 0;
    let sumNegative = 0

    if (input === null || input === []){
      return [];
    } else {
      return input.reduce(function(prev,num){
      if (num > 0) { 
      countPositive++; 
      }else{ 
      sumNegative = prev + num};
      }, 0);
    }
    return [countPositive, sumNegative];
}
```

It throws me a TypeError that says:

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

When I log 'prev' to the console inside of the reduce function, it logs undefined for all inputs except the first one. The first one, as expected, is 0. But for each following input it logs undefined. Why is this happening?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback you pass to `.reduce()` needs to return the cumulative value (the value that will be passed as `prev` to the next iteration of the loop.  Since you are returning nothing, you get `undefined` for the next iteration of your loop.

This complicates what you're trying to do because you are trying to keep track of two values in your loop.  As such, you would either have to avoid using `prev` at all or you'd have to make it be a data structure that had both your values in it.  Your use is not a textbook example for `.reduce()`.  Your code is probably simpler with an iteration using `.forEach()` or `for/of`.

```
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
    let countPositive = 0;
    let sumNegative = 0

    if (!input || input.length === 0){
      return [];
    } else {
      input.forEach(function(num){
        if (num > 0) {
          ++countPositive;
        } else { 
          sumNegative += num;
      });
    }
    return [countPositive, sumNegative];
}
```

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I remember the person teaching me about reduce() stressing that 'return' always be a part of the callback.

Comment: also note conditional testing for empty array is invalid

Comment: @newman - I added an implementation using `.forEach()` which I think is simpler than trying to make `.reduce()` fit here.

Comment: @charlietfl - Thx.  Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Well sorry but this is not a good implementation of this function. But we can correct your function as follows;

```js
function countPositivesSumNegatives(input) {
    let countPositive = 0;
    let sumNegative = 0;

    if (input === null || input === []){
      return [];
    } else {
        sumNegative = input.reduce(function(prev,num){
                                     if (num > 0) { 
                                       countPositive++;
                                     } else { 
                                         prev += num;
                                       }
                                     return prev; // <---- THE MISSING PART
                                   }, 0);
      }
    return [countPositive, sumNegative];
}
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,-4,7,-3];
console.log(countPositivesSumNegatives(data));
```

However while the code works just fine it still involves many issues. When getting into functors like `.reduce()` you should be able to keep everthing contained within itself and should not refer to variables at the outer scope. Accordingly one can simply rephrase this code as follows;

```js
var data = [1,2,3,4,5,-4,7,-3],
    cpsn = a => a.reduce((p,c) => c > 0 ? (p[0]++,p) : (p[1]+=c,p) ,[0,0]);
console.log(cpsn(data))
```